# How to align the content of 2 columns in a word table, horizontally? (Word 2010)

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to align a list of symbols, on the left column I have the symbol, on the right one its description.

[image]

There's no paragraph editor that can help me fit the spacing between the lines, how can I do this without placing a single row for every symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still access the paragraph dialog, see picture below (it is 2013, but it should be the same.)

[image: Paragraph]

Comment: Ty ;)))))))))))